# Strange Manipulate behavior

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, dynamic

Running the following code and pressing the play button under `b` will input `-2147483648` in `b`.

```
Manipulate[
 a = 2,

 {{a, 1}, ControlType -> None},
 {{b, 1}, 1, a, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

I believe this occurs only when all of these are true:

- A variable is the max value of another variable.
- Both variables have the initial value of `1`.
- The variable with the max value of the other variable has a step size.
- The variable with the max value of the other variable has the option `Appearance -> "Open"`.
- <strike>Part is used (but there are exceptions)</strike>

An exception, I found that the code works only when the value put in `a` is `1`, thus not changing the value (e.g. `a = {3, 2, 1}[[3]]`, `a = 1`).

Curiously, when the initial value of `a` or `b` is set to anything other than `1`, when the `Appearance` is not `"Open"`, or when the step size is removed, the code runs flawlessly.

I think this is a bug, but it needs to be verified by other users.

```
$Version

(* "10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)" *)
(* "10.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)" *)
```

**Edit:** `Part` seems not to be required for this to occur.

Comment: I can confirm that behavior on MMA 10.4.0 Win7-64. It only happens if I hit play right after evaluating the expression; Instead, if I first move the slider manually, then hit play, it works fine. Although I'll admit that I don't understand your `Manipulate` construct. Although I can't exactly pinpoint my unease with it, it seems to me that it would set up some unpleasant race conditions when updating variable values. When would such a construct occur?

Comment: @MarcoB It's odd that moving the slider first doesn't create the issue. On _Mathematica_ 10.3.1 and 10.1.0, the same issue occurs even after moving the slider.

Comment: @MarcoB I have a memoized function in `Initialization` that outputs a list of polygons. The length of this list changes when the input changes. The input is another slider that I did not include in my code (since that's unrelated to the issue). I needed that the max value of my slider for frame (in this case, `a`) change according to the output. This is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although syntactically correct, your `Manipulate` expression is somewhat strange. Normally, one does not initialize a control in the first argument of a `Manipulate` expression, but I know of nothing in the literature of dynamic constructs that forbids it.

On the other hand, because the order in which control variables are initialized is not clearly documented and sometimes appears to be very strange, I have come to be cautious about such initialization.

To see some of the strangeness, let us consider two variants of your code.

```
DynamicModule[{a = 3},
  Manipulate[Row[{a = 2, "  ", b}],
    {{b, 1}, 1, a, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]]
```

[image: demo1]

In this case the assignment made in 1st argument of the dynamic module sets the upper limit of control `b`. The assignment made in the 1st argument of the `Manipulate` seems to ignored or overridden in setting the upper limit of `b`. Now I will add a control specification for `a` within the `Manipulate` expression. If it has any effect, it should constrain the upper limit of `b` to 1, right?

```
DynamicModule[{a = 3},
  Manipulate[Row[{a = 2, "  ", b}],
    {{a, 1}, ControlType -> None},
    {{b, 1}, 1, a, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]]
```

[image: demo2]

Adding the control specification for `a` did have a effect, but not the one I predicted. Now the 1st argument of `Manipulate` expression is setting the upper limited of `b` Why? I don't know. However, it does have the merit of working the you expected you code to.

To get the same effect without the `DynamicModule` wrapper, you can write

```
Manipulate[Row[{a = 2, "  ", b}],
  {a, ControlType -> None},
  {{b, 1}, 1, a, 1, Appearance -> "Open"},
  Initialization :> (a = 3)]
```

It has the same behavior as the 2nd example above, and is the work-around I recommend. The value assigned to `a` doesn't have to be 3, of course. Any value the would be acceptable as the upper limit element of `b` will do, which makes me think that this value becomes the upper limit of `b` briefly during initialization, but gets overridden further along in the process.

Comment: I could not think of a better code construct that would alter the upper bound of a variable according to the output of a function. Altering a variable of a `Manipulate` inside a function declared in `Initialization` sometimes causes problems when saving and opening the manipulate/entire notebook.

Comment: @JHM. It appears that your actual problem is quite a bit more complex than the toy problem you posted here. I suggest  you ask a new question with an example that better describes your real issues. I can see no way of discussing further complications within the framework of this toy problem.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question of "why does this bug out" but this answer is a `DynamicModule` that is equivalent to your `Manipulate` that you could add your `Initialization` function to.

```
DynamicModule[
 {a = 2, b = 1},
 Panel[
  Column[{
    Manipulator[Dynamic[b], {1, a, 1}, Appearance -> "Open"],
    Framed[Dynamic[a], Background -> White, 
     ImageSize -> {500, 100}]}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I need this to be `Manipulate` because I am submitting my project to Wolfram Demonstrations.

Comment: Ah - I see. Well last time I asked they're looking to move Demonstrations onto the Cloud and might use the opportunity to extend their rules to allow DynamicModules. But I already admitted I didn't answer the question this time :)

Comment: An alternative would be not to use `"Open"` and press the + to open the controls.